# Unable to download configuration

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I have a SolrCloud instance running with a single core / collection.

I am attempting to download the configuration for this collection with the following command:

`/opt/solr-5.3.0/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:9983 -cmd downconfig -confdir /opt/solr/collection1 -confname *`

However, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error downloading files from zookeeper path /configs/bin to /opt/solr/collection1
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkConfigManager.downloadFromZK(ZkConfigManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkConfigManager.downloadConfigDir(ZkConfigManager.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkCLI.main(ZkCLI.java:230)
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /configs/bin
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1472)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$6.execute(SolrZkClient.java:328)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$6.execute(SolrZkClient.java:325)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkCmdExecutor.retryOperation(ZkCmdExecutor.java:61)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.getChildren(SolrZkClient.java:325)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkConfigManager.downloadFromZK(ZkConfigManager.java:92)
```

I do not know the confname so I am provding `*` as its value. Is that the cause of the issue?

All that I wish to know is how to download the configuration for the existing core / collection (which I then intend to upload to my own local installation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out the cause of the issue. It was the value passed to `confname` option.

The `confname` option is a mandatory option when attempting to download the configurations of an existing core / collection.

Turns out that when a configuration is uploaded to zookeeper, you don't have to specify the `confname` option - in such a case, zookeeper uses the collection name itself as the configuration name.

My collection was named `Collection1` and thus, by providing that I managed to successfully download the configuration.

The final command was:

```
/opt/solr-5.3.0/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:9983
-cmd downconfig -confdir /opt/solr/collection1 -confname Collection1
```